# Where is completion state of task instance stored in Luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I am starting with Luigi, and I wonder how does Luigi know, that it shouldn't re-run the task because it was already successfully run with the same parameters. I read through the docs, but didn't find the answer.

Hypotheses:

- Does Luigi store the state (tasks instances and their results) in memory (it doesn't use DB)? So, when I restart scheduler, it forgets everything and re-runs all tasks?
- Or, does Luigi always run [task.complete](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.task.html#luigi.task.Task.complete) for any scheduled task to see if the task should be run? Which would mean that the `complete` handler should be really quick?
- Or, does it work in a different way?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Aha, found this in [task.output](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.task.html#luigi.task.Task.output):

The output of the Task determines if the Task needs to be run–the task is considered finished iff the outputs all exist. Subclasses should override this method to return a single Target or a list of Target instances.

So, it means that the `complete` or [`output.exists`](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/task.py#L526) should be really really fast.